# How to sum rows of a 2D array individually with Java?

Tags: java, matrix

i have a matrix and I want to sum all content on the array from one point to another of the matrix, so in other words it might be that in row 1 i want to start to sum from col2 then sume row1 and row2 completely and then on row3 only until the position on number2
so leet me give you an example

```
class Lab {
    public static void main(string[] args) {
        int [][] scores = {{ 2, 8, 3, 2, 6 },
            { 3, 2, 8, 1, 0 },
            { 6, 9, 6, 3, 4 },
            { 5, 4, 2, 4, 5 }};
        outputArray(scores);
    }


public int sumRow(int[][] matrix, int row)
{
    int sum = 0;
    startrow = scores[1][]
    lastrow =scores[3][]
    startcol =scores[][2]
    lastcol = scores[][2]

    for(int i = startrow; i==lastrow;i++){
            for (int j=startcol ; j==lastcol;j++) {
                
                sum += scores[i][j];
    return sum;
}


basically the sum of 
row 1 -> 8, 1, 0
row 2 -> 6, 9, 6, 3, 4
row 3 -> 5, 4, 2

but done in one for loop (or any other method you think will be best to do so)
```

not sure if it can be done at once or if its needed to go row by row and then sum all the rows?

thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify what the program is supposed to do? We can't help unless we have a clear understanding of what the program is supposed to do.  What are the rules that cause the sum in your example to include elements at the end of row 1, all of row 2, and the beginning of row 3?

Comment: Why do you have `==` in the test conditions in your `for` loops?

Comment: Thanks @OldDogProgrammer for looking into it!  so what im trying to do is extract data from-- to not all row, so partially.. so let say i want the sum the scores but not all the scores in a row.. i want them from start  from point A to point B that means that in the start row will start to sum from col2 and in the last row will stop counting on col2 as well.. and will count all the rows in between
so i use the == becuase i want to be equal to that number not sure if that is correct or not.

Comment: The `for(int i = startrow; i==lastrow; i++)` will cause the loop to  have either zero or one pass.  This code will set the value of `i` to `startrow`, and then test the value of `i` to `lastrow`. If, initially, `startrow` is **not** equal to `lastrow`, this will cause the initial test of `i==lastrow` to be `false`, and the loop will exit without a pass. If, initially, `startrow` **is** equal to `lastrow`, this will cause the initial test of `i==lastrow` to be `true`, the loop will pass, increment `i`, and then exit because `i` will no longer be equal to `lastrow`.

Comment: thanks for the explanation @OldDogProgrammer!  then it should be  for(int i = startrow; i<lastrow; i++) ? right? but when i tried this it does also dont work as it does not iterate over all the rows only from the ones where i have marked the pos..

Comment: Yes. ` for (int i = startrow; i < lastrow; i++)` will  iterate from `startrow` to `lastrow`,  excluding `lastrow`. If you want `lastrow` to be included, use ` for (int i = startrow; i <= lastrow; i++)`.

Comment: ok but it does still not do on terms of iteration..or im doing something wrong.. so lets say we have a 12x12 matrix that the data in y axis in the  matrix represents years and the x data  the months.. and each item on the array means sales for that month, now the starting year is 2010 and the end year 2012, but lets say you want to get the sum of the rows from may 2011 till march 2014.. is that anyway a 2for loop can do that, or you need to extract first the 1s incomplete, then the 2 complete years and then the last incomplete and sum all? not sure if this clarifies my initial query or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sales by month, in my opinion, greatly clarifies what you want to do.

To accomplish that, the `sum` method should have parameters to specify the row and column of the first cell, and row and column of the last cell to be summed.

You might try something like this:

```
 public static int sumRange (  int matrix[][]
                             , int startRow, int startCol
                             , int endRow  , int endCol  ) {
      int sum = 0;
      int colIdx, rowIdx;

      // add elements at end of first row 
      for (colIdx = startCol; colIdx < matrix [0].length; colIdx++) {
         sum += matrix [startRow][colIdx];
      }

      // add elements of "in-between" rows, if any
      for (rowIdx = startRow + 1; rowIdx < endRow; rowIdx++) {
         for (colIdx = 0; colIdx < matrix [rowIdx].length; colIdx++) {
             sum += matrix [rowIdx][colIdx];
         }
      }

      // add elements at start of last row
      for (colIdx = 0; colIdx <= endCol; colIdx++) {
            sum += matrix [endRow][colIdx];
      }
      return sum;
 }
```

The above uses 4 `for` loops, but is straightforward -- almost.

You could do it with a pair of nested `for` loops, but with an `if` that has several tests.

```
 public static int sumRange (  int matrix[][]
                             , int startRow, int startCol
                             , int endRow  , int endCol   ) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int rowIdx = startRow; rowIdx <= endRow; rowIdx++) {
       for (int colIdx = 0; colIdx < matrix[rowIdx].length;colIdx++) {
           if (    rowIdx == startRow && colIdx >= startCol
                || rowIdx == endRow   && colIdx <= endCol
                || rowIdx >  startRow && rowIdx <  endRow   ) {
               sum += matrix [rowIdx][colIdx];
           }
       }
    }
    return sum;
 }
```

Is it possible to do it with one `for` loop?  It is.

```
 public static int sumRange (   int matrix[][]
                              , int startRow, int startCol
                              , int endRow  , int endCol   ) {
 int sum = 0;
 int len = matrix[0].length;

 for (  int idx =   len * startRow + startCol ;
            idx <=  len * endRow   + endCol   ;
            idx++ ) {
    sum += matrix [idx / len] [idx % len];   
 }
 
 return sum;
 }
```

There are preconditons:

- All rows in `matrix` have the same length.
- The values for `startRow`, `endRow`, `startCol`, `endCol` are valid when used as row and column indices for the `matrix` parameter.
- In the first two examples, `startRow <  endRow`.
- In the third example,      `startRow <= endRow` . If `startRow == endRow`, then `startCol < endCol`.

Note the 2nd precondition implies the first two examples won't work when `startRow == endRow`. To fix the bug, precede the first `for` loop with an `if` statement to check for that, a `for` loop to sum the proper columns, and a `return` statement.

Because, in your example, the matrix was included as a parameter, and there was no use of instance variables, I made the methods `static` in these examples. If the matrix the method is supposed to use is an instance variable, remove `int matrix [][]` from the parameter list, and remove `static` from the method header.

Comment: Note: The computer I am using does not have an IDE. I did not test the code in this example. I did not even attempt to compile it. If you find an error in the code, please correct it.

Comment: Another way to fix the limitation or bug in the 2nd example is to extend the `if` statement  with something like this:   `|| startRow == endRow && colIndex >= startCol && colIndex <= endCol`